# Formatting text like an ACT English passage in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I'm working on a textbook that needs to approximate/recreate new content formatted like the English section of the ACT college entrance exam, which has text that looks like this:
[image: ACT English content]

Here are my main concerns in the LaTeX formatting trickery:

- The numbered questions in the right column always need to appear on the same line (directly across from the underlined portion in the left column). I assume the best way to do this is to format all the text in one table so that I can control what is in each row rather than have the text as a paragraph in each separate column, which could cause them not to align exactly (I think.)
- The number for the question appears underneath the underlined portion. I'm really not sure how to do this in LaTeX apart from using \tabto and writing the number in a separate row underneath the text, which would require a lot of trial and error to get the placements just right.

Any input on making this all work would be appreciated!

Comment: For the 2nd part, use `stackengine` package.  Then, `\stackunder{\underline{and my idol}}{\scriptsize 1}`

Comment: Re: above comment, might need to `\smash` it if it affects line spacing.  Adding an MWE to your question would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll see if I can get it to work with this package. I did a search for MWE to try to figure out what it stands for without having to ask like a doofus, but from the context I can't figure out what it is...

Comment: @Steve So \stackunder definitely does what I want it to do, but as you suspected it does create extra space between the rows that I'm trying to suppress. How exactly can I use \smash along with the \stackunder syntax to keep the line spacing more even?

Comment: Unless the underlined portion takes up the whole line, then `\smash{\stackunder{\underline{and my idol}}{\scriptsize 1}}` would make the stack allocate zero vertical height and depth for its placement.

Comment: An MWE is a "minimum working example".  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Perfect! \smash with \stackunder does exactly what I need it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a MWE from the OP, I had to guess at how certain things were supposed to work (i.e., left/right coordination).  But since James indicated the stacking approach worked for him, I wrote up a possible approach using that method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,stackengine,enumitem}
\newcounter{undertag}
\newcommand\utag[1]{\stepcounter{undertag}%
  \smash{\stackunder[2pt]{\underline{#1}}{\scriptsize\theundertag}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\parindent30pt
\doublespacing
\centerline{\bfseries Ukelele Life}

My older sister was a guitar buff \utag{and my idol} when I was growing up.
She would teach me songs on her acousic guitar...
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\vspace*{8pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\theundertag.] If the writer were to delete the underlined portion, 
  the paragraphwould primarily lose:
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*.,topsep=0pt]
  \item an indication that the narrator learned to play guitar at a relatively
    young age.
  \item an indication of why the narrator became interested in playing the guitar.
  \item ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]